# Dynamically change Jquery UI draggable helper width and change tolerance effect in droppable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

**How to dynamically change Jquery UI draggable helper width and change tolerance effect in droppable?**

Case: when I make one helper in jquery ui draggable . then this draggable object put into droppable area . in droppable , ***over function have to change this helper width***. so in this function changed width of helper Object but  ***tolerance effect  is not work***  in droppable. see code:

```
// let the gallery items be draggable
            $( ".elementDrag", elementContainer ).draggable({
                    revert: "invalid",
                    //helper: "clone",
                     helper: function(event) {

                        DOM2 = $('<div style="border: 1px solid;"></div>');
                        DOM2.outerWidth(passObj.width + 20);
                        DOM2.outerHeight(passObj.height);

                        return DOM2;
                                                      },
                    cursor: "move",
                    start: function(event, ui) 
                     {

                     },
                    stop: function(event, ui) 
                     {

                     }
                });



pageContainer.droppable({
                accept: ".elementDrag",
                tolerance: "fit",
                greedy: true,
                drop: function( event, ui ) 
                {
                                    outerContainer.removeClass('over');
                },
                over: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log(ui);
                    console.log(ui.helper);
                    console.log($(ui.helper).outerWidth());
                    // new width set but tolerance effect is not work .... 
                    $(ui.helper).outerWidth($(ui.helper).outerWidth() - 20);

                    console.log($(ui.helper).outerWidth());

                     outerContainer.addClass('over');
                },
                out: function() {
                     outerContainer.removeClass('over');
                }
            })
```